# If you have different accounts on ps4 do you have to purchase internet cards for each account or will one work on both accounts

Tags: ps4, psn

My boyfriend purchased a PlayStation internet card for the PS4 for his account. Just wondering if it would work on my account or do I need to purchase my own subscription for my account?

Comment: What is a "PlayStation internet card"? Are you referring to a voucher card that can be redeemed to pay for purchases or add money to your account balance? OR are you referring to a PS Plus subscription which provides you access to online gaming amongst some other benefits?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're referring to a PSN Card which allows you to load some money onto your account. Each PSN Card has a unique code and each code can only be used once. So you have to buy separate cards for each of your accounts.

Comment: She might be talking about PS Plus - hence online play. The answer is still yes, - 1 digital item per account.

Answer (score 0):

> do I need to purchase my own subscription for my account?

I am assuming that you are talking about a **PlayStation Plus** account.  Please let us know if that's not the case (just guessing what a PlayStation "internet card" is). I am also assuming that the two of you are sharing one physical PS4 console.  If so, then the answer is "not necessarily."

If your boyfriend sets your PS4 as his "primary console," then you ***will*** be able to play things like network games (ex: Star Wars Battlefront multiplayer) and even the free PSPlus games that he downloads.  Again, this is assuming that you are logged-in with your account on the same PS4 that he has set as his "primary."